# C++ Member Function Pointers and STL Algorithm

Tags: c++, stl, function-pointers, pointer-to-member

I have an abstract functor class that overloads operator() and derived objects that implement it.

I have a function (part of another class) that tries to take an Array of these functor classes and tries to pass a pointer to a member function to the std algorithm for_each(), here is a overview of what I'm doing:

EDIT: I have re-cleaned it and put the old small example for clarity.

```
class A{
  operator()(x param)=0;
  operator()(y param)=0;
}

class B: public A{
  operator()(x param); //implemented
  operator()(y param);
}
...// and other derived classes from A

void ClassXYZ::function(A** aArr, size_t aSize)
{
  ...//some code here

  for(size_t i = 0; i< aSize; i++){

    A* x = aArr[i];
    for(v.begin(), v.end(), ...//need to pass pointer/functor to right operator() of x here

..//other code
}
```

I've tried a few ways and I can't figure out how to get it to work, I need to use the abstract type as I could have different derived types but they will all have to implement the same operator()(param x) function.

I just need the for_each() function to be able to call the member function operator()(param x). I have a different function where it has concrete implementations and simply passes an instance of those and it works. I'm trying to achieve a similar effect here but without the knowledge of what concrete classes I'm given.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why don't you use a `vector` instead of pointers to pointers?

Comment: @GMan: Pointers-to-pointers are needed to enable each item in the array to be of any type derived from A (otherwise you'd get slicing). A vector doesn't actually help much here because it won't automatically `delete` its pointer members -- you would need to use a vector of smart pointers for that.

Comment: OK good but please fix the body of `function()` -- currently the for loop opening brace isn't closed!  And what is `it`?  And what is `X`?  (Did you mean `x` instead of `X`?) Etc.

Comment: Wait a minute -- do both `operator()()`s take a single parameter of the same type???  If so then I'm surprised that the function definitions even compile...  and of course there's then no way for the compiler to distinguish the function types, as they *are the same type*!

Comment: no it takes a single parameter of different types x and y. Alrite i'm gonna try and post the whole snippet. Were getting close I think.

Comment: "no it takes a single parameter of different types x and y" -- the way you've written it, the two functions both take a single parameter of type `param` -- only the name (not the type) of the parameter is different.  Parameter names don't affect the function type.

Comment: Sorry error, it's the other way around but the snippet above is pretty much what ive got. I could put up the full snippet i have but it might clutter it with unrelated junk. But i'll try and put the full snippet in a clean way.

Comment: Okay i put cleaned up version of the snippet up

Comment: You got my `static_cast<>` suggestion wrong (`pFunc` is not a type), and `bind1st()` wants a pointer to an object, not an object. Try `for_each(it->second.begin(), it->second.end(), std::bind1st(std::mem_fun(pFunc), pf));`

Comment: Yeah i've tried that I get the same error as above. I've just been running out of ideas and trying all sorts of things like typedefs with static_cast and objects instead of pointers :( That was a snapshot of my last attempt.

Comment: Your () are in the wrong place. It looks like you've got bind1st(mem_fun(pFunc,pf)) rather than bind1st(mem_fun(pFunc),pf).

Comment: Maybe if all else fails, I could modify my base class so all derived class have to provide a pointer or a functor to a member function for each overloaded operator.

Comment: @alex nah I just checked it's alrite, i think eyes are playing tricks on us. The error message is interesting though, something about cannot overload second operator if you read above in my question... hmm?

Comment: Could you please change the code to what either I or Alex suggested and also show the corresponding error message (formatted nicely please)?

Comment: Okay i've done what you or alex have said : std::bind1st(std::mem_fun(pFunc), pf) and also using static_cast. The errors are same which I have formatted a bit better and put up in the re-edited question after the source code.

Comment: Thanks iQ. I believe the underlying problem is that you can't pass reference arguments to `bind1st()` in current versions of C++ -- it will try to create a reference to a reference, which is currently deemed illegal (though this will be fixed in C++0x).  Google "bind1st reference", e.g.: http://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-bugs/2008-10/msg00798.html.  Very sad :(

Comment: Aww, I had a feeling, i mentioned that in one of the comments earlier :( so what other solutions then? If i want to create a pure virtual return functor/member function pointer class then i'll probably come across the same problem? Maybe just pointers that should work hopefully

Comment: I'd suggest writing your own accessor: `struct dospeed { PerformerFunctor* _pf; dospeed(PerformerFunctor* pf) : _pf(pf) {} void operator()(SpeedInfo& x) { return _pf(x); } };` Then the 3rd arg to `for_each()` is just `dospeed(pf)`.

Comment: thanks j_i'll go with that then, i'm gna try it out. One last thing if i changed it from reference to pointers how do I make for_each pass pointers instead of actual objects? which is what it does now

Comment: Not sure exactly what you mean, but if you wanted `for_each()` to pass pointers to SpeedInfo then I think you would actually need a container of pointer-to-SpeedInfo rather than a container of SpeedInfo. But why do you want that anyway? (If that's what you actually want -- otherwise please elaborate.)

Comment: No its alrite I used a accessor struct. I was just curious if there was a way for for_each() to pass address values of objects as in &obj instead of just sending obj. But I appreciate your help and advice thank you.

Comment: No problem. But if you receive the parameter by reference (as I did in the `dospeed` comment), you can of course take the address of that reference to get a pointer-to-SpeedInfo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand what you want to do, there are quite a few errors in your code snippet:

- `sizeof aArr` is wrong, you need to pass the size explicitly (noticed by ChrisW)
- Missing `virtual` specifier on the original declaration of `operator()()`
- Not sure where your `for` loop ends as there's no matching `}` (I suspect it shouldn't be there at all)

Here's some code that will loop through an array of `A` (or `A`-derived) objects and call `operator()` on each one, passing across a passed-in argument as the `param` parameter:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>

using namespace std;

typedef double param;      // Just for concreteness

class A {
public:
    virtual void operator()(param x) = 0;
};

class B : public A {
public:
    void operator()(param x) { cerr << "This is a B!  x==" << x << ".\n"; }
};

void function(A** aArr, size_t n, param theParam) {
    void (A::*sFunc)(param x) = &A::operator();
    for_each(aArr, aArr + n, bind2nd(mem_fun(sFunc), theParam));
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    A* arr[] = { new B(), new B(), new B() };

    function(arr, 3, 42.69);

    delete arr[0];
    delete arr[1];
    delete arr[2];
    return 0;
}
```

`mem_fun()` is necessary to convert a 1-parameter member function pointer to a 2-parameter function object; `bind2nd()` then produces from that a 1-parameter function object that fixes the argument supplied to `function()` as the 2nd argument.  (`for_each()` requires a 1-parameter function pointer or function object.)

**EDIT:** Based on [Alex Tingle's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1451160/c-member-function-pointers-and-stl-algorithm-problem/1451279#1451279), I infer that you might have wanted `function()` to do many things on a single `A`-derived object.  In that case, you'll want something like:

```
void function(A** aArr, size_t n, vector<param> const& params) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        void (A::*sFunc)(param x) = &A::operator();
        for_each(params.begin(), params.end(), bind1st(mem_fun(sFunc), aArr[i]));
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes i'll try that, since this is full standard c++. I do have virtual i just forgot to leave it out from example and i'll fix the size of arr as well. I'll post back if it works, should do.

Comment: With the for_each loop, it is actually working on a vector of some values. So i need the functors to act on those data. so the for_each(v.begin(), v.end(), func) where v is the vector and func is the pointer i'm trying to get out from the aArr

Comment: If you reread you might find I anticipated that... :) If not, let me know what needs changing.

Comment: Yeah i can't any of the solutions to work, I think i maybe doing something wrong on my part. As a general question how would you get a pointer to a member function if all your given is a pointer to an instance?

Comment: Do you realise that "pointer-to-member-function" is a different *category* of type than "pointer-to-function"? It is *not* possible to convert from one to the other. However you can get an object that can be called like a function from a combination of pointer-to-object and pointer-to-member-function using `bind1st(mem_fun(pMemFunc), pObj)`.

Comment: yep that's what i've been trying to do but I always get : error: no matching function for call to ‘mem_fun(<unresolved overloaded function type>) ---- so I thought i must be doing something wrong, I get a pointer to an object and i've tried passing the de referenced pointer and the pointer itself. No luck.

Comment: AHAA wait i'm re-editing my question, I know the source of the problem i think

Answer (score 4):

You want something like this...

```
std::for_each(
  it->second.begin(),
  it->second.end(),
  std::bind1st(std::mem_fun(&A::operator()),x)
);
```

Comment: Nice. Also `bind1st()` from the regular C++03 standard will work in place of the more general `std::tr1::bind()` you have used here (which may not be supported by all compilers yet).

Comment: A nice example of how generic you can be with C++, but it's such a pain on the eyes. :-/

Comment: mem_fun() converts a unary member function - called like obj->fun(arg) - into a binary normal function - called like fun(obj,arg).

Comment: That doesn't compile for me :( I get: error: no matching function for call to ‘mem_fun(<unresolved overloaded function type>)’|

Comment: I think it probably doesn't like the fact I have inheritance running through and the function is an overloaded operator.

Comment: @iQ: If overloading is a problem, use a static_cast<> to specify which operator() you want, e.g.: `mem_fun(static_cast<void (A::*)(param)>(&A::operator())`

Comment: Gah! - j_random_hacker: We're swiftly degenerating to coding line noise.

Comment: yes thats exactly the problem, overloading! @alex I've tried that before but it didn't like it, something about typename operation and invalid cast from const A to A*, I will try static_cast by j_random.

Comment: @iQ: Alex's and my approaches are basically equivalent -- if his doesn't work, mine won't and vice versa. Your error must be from somewhere else. PLEASE post a complete snippet of the code you have, there are far too many problems (e.g. mismatched braces!) with your current one.

Comment: Lol sorry I'll try and post the full code snippet, I just wanted to make it simple so i made the code up based on it. One sec I will do it.

Answer (score 1):

The expression "bar.*fn" doesn't evaluate to regular, or non-member, function pointer. 
So you need to call a binding function (either std::tr1::bind or boost::bind ) to obtain such a function.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get it work using the current format, I think it doesn't like the fact i'm using a Pointer to a base member function and trying to call a derived classes implementation like that.

Instead I modified the code to include pure virtual functions in the base class that will return functors for each derived class when implemented. I can't think of anything else that would work. But it compiles like this.

But I am curious if anyone has a solution to the original problem without having to use pure virtual "create functor" methods in the base class.